# Regex to match on specific string and number values

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to create a regex that will allow a specific string only (Test1) for example or numeric values. How would I do this? I have tried the following but it doesn't work and won't notice the string part. What am I doing wrong with this regex?

```
^Test1[0-9]*$
```

I want to use it in an MVC model validation attribute:

```
  [RegularExpression("^Test1[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be numeric or be Test1.")]
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `^(Test1|[0-9]*)$`? To match `Test1` or *zero or more digits*?

Comment: *(Test1) for example or numeric values* => `^(?:Test1|[0-9]+)$`

Comment: `^Test1|\d+$` will match "Test1" or any numeric value.

Comment: No unless you enclose branches in parentheses. @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: @revo What? OP isn't asking to capture any groups. My expression is fine.

Comment: I didn't mean capturing but grouping. Yours simply matches a string like `string123` @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: @revo Ah yes, you're correct.

Comment: There is no point in arguing what kind of group to use, capturing or non-capturing here. The performance gain is next to none, and I noticed that a lot of users prefer readability to overoptimization. Theomax, does `^(Test1|[0-9]*)$` work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern - `^Test1[0-9]*$` - matches an entire string with the following contents: `Test1` followed with 0 or more digits.

If you meant to match either `Test1` or zero or more digits as a whole string, you need

```
^(Test1|[0-9]*)$
```

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(` - [**grouping construct**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) start:

  - `Test1` - either `Test1`
  - `|` - or (this is an [**alternation operator**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html))
  - `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `)` - grouping construct end (it forcesd `^` and `$` anchors be applied to each of the alternatives above)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer - how would I modify your suggestion to specify the number of digits must be 4? I tried the following but it doesn't work: ^Test1|[0-9]{4}+$

Comment: Use `^(Test1|[0-9]{4})$`. Do not forget the parentheses, they are crucial here. Else, you'd need to repeat the anchors in every branch: `^Test1$|^[0-9]{4}$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me solve more problems.

Answer (score 1):

- How about `|` operator between `Test1` and `[0-9]*`?
- How about replacing `*` with `+` - thanks to that empty strings won't be catched?

Regex `^Test1|[0-9]+$` should match all *Test1*, *123*, *0*, *12345* and so on.

In terms of MVC - it has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: Agreed it is not related to MVC just wanted to add abit more context to the question :)

Comment: [`^Test1|[0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pmTpY5/1) also finds a match in `Test1$%^&^%$##` and `_______________________________-5`.